# Intersection with 2 KML files - newbie

Tags: kml, ogr, intersection

I'm new to all this gis thing and I have this project for university where I'm trying to find the countries within a bounding box. So what I'm doing is, I have a set of coordinates that define a bounding box, I then create a kml out of that, and now I need to intersect the geometries (or at least, intersect the bounding boxes).
So far, with the help of this community, I was able to read the files. But I can't seem to get the geometry for my countries. Can someone help me?

My Countries Border file http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7a8585998b7f470b85235dcdb560c7e2

My Code:

```
    import json
    from osgeo import ogr, osr
    from osgeo import gdal, osr
    import tempfile

    bb= [[-77.452393, 58.997295], [-70.229156, 59.743305], [-69.136154, 55.907402], [-75.653404, 55.193794], [-77.452393, 58.997295]]

    def bb_2_wkt(bb):
      #bb= [[-77.452393, 58.997295], [-70.229156, 59.743305], [-69.136154, 55.907402], [-75.653404, 55.193794], [-77.452393, 58.997295]]
      #POLYGON ((-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295))
      r = 'POLYGON (('
      for i in range(0, len(bb)):
        r = r+str(bb[0][0])+' '+str(bb[0][1])
        if i +1<len(bb):
          r = r+','
      r = r +'))'
      return r

    def bb_2_kml(bb):
      #bb= [[-77.452393, 58.997295], [-70.229156, 59.743305], [-69.136154, 55.907402], [-75.653404, 55.193794], [-77.452393, 58.997295]]
      #<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><coordinates>8.1848144531,45.8179931641 10.4920501709,45.8179931641 10.4920501709,48.1844011251 8.1848144531,48.1844011251</coordinates></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
      r = ''
      for i in range(0, len(bb)):
        r = r+str(bb[0][0])+','+str(bb[0][1])+',0'
        if i +1<len(bb):
          r = r+'\n'
      r = r +'))'

      #return """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><coordinates>"""+r+"""</coordinates></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></kml>"""
      return """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Placemark><name>The Pentagon</name><Polygon><extrude>1</extrude><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>"""+r+"""</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark></kml>"""


    ########

    # Create tempfile for ogr driver read
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    temp.write(bb_2_kml(bb))
    temp.flush()

    # Read XML file into python
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('LIBKML')
    datasource = driver.Open(temp.name)
    #layer = datasource.GetLayer()
    #feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
    ###


    #driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('LIBKML')
    #datasource = driver.Open('/home/pegg/geocoding/World_Country_Borders_KML.kml')
    #layer = datasource.GetLayer()
    #feat = layer.GetNextFeature()

    # Convert ogr feature to GEOSGeometry
    #feat_json = json.loads(feat.ExportToJson())
    #feat_json['geometry']['coordinates'] = feat_json['geometry']['coordinates'][0:2]
    #geom = json.dumps(feat_json['geometry'])
    #pnt = GEOSGeometry(geom)




    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('LIBKML')
    shp1 = driver.Open('/home/pegg/World_Country_Borders_KML.kml')

    #shp2 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(bb_2_wkt(bb))
    shp2 = datasource

    SpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    SpatialRef.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')


    # Create dst file here
    dstdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

    import os
    if os.path.isfile('/home/pegg/geocoding/layers/mylayer.shp'):
       os.remove('/home/pegg/geocoding/layers/mylayer.shp')
       os.remove('/home/pegg/geocoding/layers/mylayer.dbf')
       os.remove('/home/pegg/geocoding/layers/mylayer.shx')


    dstshp = dstdriver.CreateDataSource('/home/pegg/geocoding/layers')
    dstlayer = dstshp.CreateLayer('mylayer',geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)


    # define its attribute fields for dstlayer and create them

    layer1 = shp1.GetLayer(0)
    layer2 = shp2.GetLayer(0)

    for feature1 in layer1:
      geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
      country_name = feature1.GetField('description')
      coords = feature1.GetField('extrude')
      #if coords == -1:
      #    continue
      print country_name
      for feature2 in layer2:
          geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()
          attribute2 = feature2.GetField('FieldName2')
          intersection = geom2.intersection(geom1)
          dstfeature = ogr.Feature(dstlayer.GetLayerDefn())
          dstfeature.SetGeometry(intersection)
          dstfeature.setField(country_name)
          dstfeature.setField(attribute2)
          dstfeature.Destroy() # and other features must be destroyed too
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste_stack.py", line 116, in <module>
    attribute2 = feature2.GetField('FieldName2')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 2845, in GetField
    raise ValueError("Illegal field requested in GetField()")
ValueError: Illegal field requested in GetField()
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: No, due to the if coords == -1, but if i remove it i Get the error on the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the answer to my problem. hope it helps someone

```
def findCountryByBoundingBoxOffline(coords):
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    bb = getBoundingBox(coords)
    path = 'borders'

    file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),path, 'World_Country_Borders_KML.kml')

    #SpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    #SpatialRef.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')

    # Read XML file into python
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
    datasource = driver.Open(file)
    layer = datasource.GetLayer()
    ##print bb
    polybb = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(bb_2_wkt(checkIfCoordsAreCircular(bb)))
    #polybb= ogr.CreateGeometryFromGML(bb2gml(bb))

    country = list()

    for i in range(0,len(layer)):
      #print '\n New layer'
      #feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
      #feat_json = json.loads(feat.ExportToJson())
      #a=json_2_wkt(feat_json)
      #poly2 = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(a)

      #intersection = polybb.Intersection(poly2)


      feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
      feat_json = json.loads(feat.ExportToJson())

      prop= feat_json['properties']
      s=str(prop)
      #{"Name": "", "Description": "<div class=\\"googft-info-window\\" style=\\"font-family:sans-serif\\"> <b>Name:</b> Algeria </div>"}
      #126chars
      name = s[110:len(s)-9]


      #bad geometries in KML
      if name == 'Antarctica' or name == 'Russia':
        a = findCountryByBoundingBoxOnline(coords)
        if a:
            country.append(a)


      b = feat_json['geometry']
      p = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(json.dumps(b, sort_keys=False))


      intersection = polybb.Intersection(p)
      if str(intersection) != "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY":
        if 'MULTIPOLYGON' in str(intersection) or 'POLYGON' in str(intersection):
          #print 'intersects at ' + name
          country.append(name)
          log.debug('intersection at '+name)
      #if (i+1)==len(layer):
        #print json.dumps(feat_json, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
        #print json.dumps(feat_json, sort_keys=False)
        #print '\n'

        #print geom_gml

    return country

def bb_2_wkt(bb):
  #bb= [[-77.452393, 58.997295], [-70.229156, 59.743305], [-69.136154, 55.907402], [-75.653404, 55.193794], [-77.452393, 58.997295]]
  #POLYGON ((-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295,-77.452393 58.997295))
  r = 'POLYGON (('
  for i in range(0, len(bb)):
    r = r+str(bb[i][0])+' '+str(bb[i][1])
    if i +1<len(bb):
      r = r+','
  r = r +'))'
  return r

def getBoundingBox(coords):
  ##parse coords

  coordsx=[] #lat
  coordsy=[] #long

  for c in range(0,len(coords)):
    coordsx.append(coords[c][0])
    coordsy.append(coords[c][1])

  xmax = max(coordsx)
  xmin = min(coordsx)
  ymax = max(coordsy)
  ymin = min(coordsy)
```

Comment: please mark your answer as accepted if this solves your problem
https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/